# How are heaps created in mixed language applications?

Tags: c++, c, windows, vb6

We have a front end written in Visual Basic 6.0 that calls several back end DLLs written in mixed C/C++.  The problem is that each DLL appears to have its own heap and one of them isn’t big enough.  The heap collides with the program stack when we’ve allocated enough memory.
Each DLL is written entirely in C, except for the basic DLL wrapper, which is written in C++.  Each DLL has a handful of entry points.  Each entry point immediately calls a C routine.  We would like to increase the size of the heap in the DLL, but haven’t been able to figure out how to do that.  I searched for guidance and found these MSDN articles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh405351(v=VS.85).aspx

These articles are interesting but provide conflicting information.  In our problem it appears that each DLL has its own heap.  This matches the “Heaps: Pleasures and Pains” article that says that the C Run-Time (C RT) library creates its own heap on startup.  The “Managing Heap Memory” article says that the C RT library allocated out of the default process heap.  The “Memory management options in Win32” article says the behavior depends on the version of the C RT library being used.

We’ve temporarily solved the problem by allocating memory from a private heap.  However, in order to improve the structure of this very large complex program, we want to switch from C with a thin C++ wrapper to real C++ with classes.  We’re pretty certain that the new and free operator won’t allocate memory from our private heap and we’re wondering how to control the size of the heap C++ uses to allocate objects in each DLL.  The application needs to run in all versions of desktop Windows-NT, from 2000 through 7.

**The Question**

> Can anyone point us to definitive and correct documentation that
>   explains how to control the size of the heap C++ uses to allocate
>   objects?

Several people have asserted that stack corruption due to heap allocations overwriting the stack are impossible.  Here is what we observed.  The VB front end uses four DLLs that it dynamicly loads.  Each DLL is independant of the others and provides a handful of methods called by the front end. All the DLLs comunicate via data structures written to files on disk.  These data structures are all structured staticlly.  They contain no pointers, just value types and fixed sized arrays of value types.  The problem DLL is invoked by a single call where a file name is passed.  It is designed to allocate about 20MB of data structures required to do complete its processing.  It does a lot of calculation, writes the results to disk, releases the 20MB of data structures, and returns and error code.  The front end then unloads the DLL.  While debugging the problem under discussion, we set a break point at the beginning of the data structure allocation code and watched the memory values returned from the calloc calls and compared them with the current stack pointer.  We watched as the allocated blocks approached the the stack.  After the allocation was complete the stack began to grow until it overlapped the heap.  Eventually the calculations wrote into the heap and corrupted the stack.  As the stack unwound it tried to return to an invalid address and crashed with a segmentation fault.

Each of our DLLs is staticly linked to the CRT, so that each DLL has its own CRT heap and heap manager.  Microsoft says in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460(v=vs.80).aspx:

> Each copy of the CRT library has a separate and distinct state. 
>   As such, CRT objects such as file handles, environment variables, and 
>   locales are only valid for the copy of the CRT where these objects are 
>   allocated or set. When a DLL and its users use different copies of the 
>   CRT library, you cannot pass these CRT objects across the DLL boundary 
>   and expect them to be picked up correctly on the other side.
>   Also, because each copy of the CRT library has its own heap manager, 
>   allocating memory in one CRT library and passing the pointer across a 
>   DLL boundary to be freed by a different copy of the CRT library is a 
>   potential cause for heap corruption.

We don't pass pointers between DLLs.  We aren't experiencing heap corruption, we are experiencing stack corruption.

Comment: Hope you get a proper answer, but in case you don't you can always override the `new` and `delete` operators to work with a private heap.

Comment: Thanks.  I know we can do that, but it is a rather complex solution.  It would be much simpler to increase the size of the heap provided by the run-time if we can figure how to do it.  We are only using a private heap because we haven't yet been able to figure this out.

Comment: Collision is impossible. Please clarify.

Comment: You seem very confident that what we observed is impossible.  I have been searching for documentation that describes stack and heap allocation and have only found descriptions that apply in very simplistic scenarios.  Could you point me toward the documents that convince you that this isn't possible?

Comment: Edward, you're saying that you're experiencing stack corruption.  Tell us how you came to this conclusion.  Also, stack corruption is different from _"The heap collides with the program stack"_, so which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the question is:

> Can anyone point us to definitive and correct documentation that
>   explains how to control the size of the heap C++ uses to allocate
>   objects?

I am going to answer my own question.  I got the answer from reading [Raymond Chen](http://microsoftjobsblog.com/blog/raymond-chen/)'s blog [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/), specifically [There's also a large object heap for unmanaged code, but it's inside the regular heap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/30/10218384.aspx).  In that article Raymond recommends [Advanced Windows Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321374460) by Mario Hewardt and Daniel Pravat.  This book has very specific information on both stack and heap corruption, which is what I wanted to know.  As a plus it provides all sorts of information about how to debug these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please elaborate on this your statement:

> The heap collides with the program stack when we’ve allocated enough memory.

If we're talking about Windows (or any other mature platform), this should not be happening: the OS makes sure that stacks, heaps, mapped files and other objects never intersect.

Also:

> Can anyone point us to definitive and correct documentation that explains how to control the size of the heap C++ uses to allocate objects?

The heap size is not fixed on Windows: it grows as the application uses more and more memory.  It will grow until all available virtual memory space for the process is used.  It is pretty easy to confirm this: just write a simple test app which keeps allocating memory and counts how much has been allocated.  On a default 32-bit Windows you'll reach almost 2Gb.  Surely, initially the heap doesn't occupy all available space, therefore it must grow in the process.

Without many details about the "collision" it's hard to tell what's happening in your case.  However, looking at the tags to this question prompts me to one possibility.  It is possible (and happens quite often, unfortunately) that ownership of allocated memory areas is being passed between modules (DLLs in your case).  Here's the scenario:

- there are two DLLs: A and B.  Both of them created their own heaps
- the DLL A allocates an object in its heap and passes the pointer and ownership to B
- the DLL B receives the pointer, uses the memory and deallocates the object

If the heaps are different, most heap managers would not check if the memory region being deallocated actually belongs to it (mostly for performance reasons).  So they would deacllocate something which doesn't belong to them.  By doing that they corrupt the other module's heap.  This may (and often does) lead to a crash.  But not always.  Depending on your luck (and particular heap manager implementation), this operation may change one of the heaps in a manner that the next allocation will happen outside of the area where the heap is located.

This often happens when one module is managed code, while the other is native one.  Since you have the VB6 tag in the question, I'd check if this is the case.

Comment: You might check back as I've added more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If the stack grows large enough to hit the heap, a prematurely aborted stack overflow may be the problem: Invalid data is passed that does not satisfy the exit condition of some recursion (loop detection is not working or not existing) in the problem DLL so that an infinite recursion consumes ridiculously large stack space. One would expect such a DLL to terminate with a stack overflow exception, but for maybe compiler / linker optimizations or large foreign heap sizes it crashes elsewhere.

Comment: We specifically don't see a stack overflow.  The amazing thing is that the total allocated space for this application rarely exceeds 40MB total.  We have been assuming that VB6 is doing some optimization to deal with a Win95 memory management issue and that now unnecessary optimization is causing us problems.  I'm prepared to be wrong about that.

Comment: ... in which case you don't link to MSVCPxx and the new operator will have its private heap too. The downside is that every template class from STL/WTL/ATL will be compiled into your C++ DLL making it larger in size. Also if you wish to employ boost in your C++ DLL(s), you might need to compile the lot for static linkage.

Answer (score 0):

Heaps are created by the CRT. That is to say, the `malloc` heap is created by the CRT, and is unrelated to `HeapCreate()`. It's not used for large allocations, though, which are handed off to the OS directly.

With multiple DLLs, you might have multiple heaps (newer VC versions are better at sharing, but even VC6 had no problem if you used MSVCRT.DLL - that's shared)

The stack, on the other hand, is managed by the OS. Here you see why multiple heaps don't matter: The OS allocation for the different heaps will never collide with the OS allocation for the stack.

Mind you, the OS may allocate heap space close to the stack. The rule is just no overlap, after all, there's no guaranteed "unused separation zone".  If you then have a buffer overflow, it could very well overflow into the stack space.

So, any solutions? Yes: move to VC2010. It has buffer security checks, implemented in quite an efficient way. They're the default even in release mode.